# Trying to use groupby to get the most common value and getting an IndexError

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, nan

I am currently doing a project for school and I encountered a little problem. I have an airbnb dataset and I'm currently trying to fill some NaN values that I have on a column called Property_type with the most common value for property type for the different categories of the column ''accommodates'' (which gives back how many people that specific airbnb can take).

Here's a sample of the columns

```
property_type   accommodates

Townhouse         2
Apartment         3
Townhouse         4
Townhouse         2
NaN               3
Townhouse         2
House             3
...               ...
```

In this case, what I would want to do is find the most frequent type of property type that accommodates 3 people and fill the NaN values with that type of property.

My problem is in getting that most common value (I know what to do afterwards, but this step is not working)

I tried to find the most common values with this code

```
property_type_mode = airbnb[['property_type','accommodates']].groupby(['accommodates']).agg(lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0])
```

This returns the error:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I don't get why, because I've done similar things for other columns and it works.

Does anyone know what I can do to solve it!!

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is returned empty index array (one reason are missing values), so selecting return error. Solution is use `next` with `iter` with possible add value if no match:

```
f = lambda x: next(iter(x.value_counts().index), 'no match')
s = airbnb.groupby('accommodates')['property_type'].agg(f)

airbnb['property_type'] = airbnb['property_type'].fillna(airbnb['accommodates'].map(s))
```

Another solution is use  [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

```
f = lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]
s = airbnb.dropna(subset=['accommodates']).groupby('accommodates')['property_type'].agg(f)

airbnb['property_type'] = airbnb['property_type'].fillna(airbnb['accommodates'].map(s))
```